# How to send text File/zip File from Restful server to the Android Client

Tags: android, web-services, rest

I wanted to ask again my Question.
I'm developing a restful web service that can be accessed from Android but I have a problem since 2 Weeks.
I want to write a service that takes some byte array from Database and write this ones to a file so that I can use this service from android.
With Android I want to get this File and then use this bytes to plot a graph.

Can you give me some Tips please!!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web API is a good option in your case, cause is very straightforward to use it and you only need to send a simple stream.Then create your own RestClient in your app for consuming the web service, here you have some code using HttpClient for doing this:

```
public void executeRequest(HttpUriRequest request, String url)  {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse httpResponse;

    try{
       httpResponse = client.execute(request);
       responseCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

       HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
       if (entity != null)
       {
           InputStream in = entity.getContent();
           response = convertStreamToString(in);
           in.close();
       }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e)  {
        client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}

private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

With this you can pass a GET request in order to get the data you need, if you need to add some extra parameters to the querystring this should be good too:

```
public void Execute(RequestMethod method) throws Exception
    {

                String combinedParams = "";
                if  (!params.isEmpty())
                {
                    combinedParams += "?";

                    for (NameValuePair p : params)
                    {
                        String paramString = p.getName() + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(p.getValue(),"UTF-8");

                        if  (combinedParams.length() > 1)
                            combinedParams += "&" + paramString;
                        else
                            combinedParams += paramString;
                    }
                }

                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url + combinedParams);

                for (NameValuePair h : headers)
                    request.addHeader(h.getName(),h.getValue());

                executeRequest(request, url);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The Problem with my work is that I have to work with a database, where blob(byte array) data that are about 100 MB. Some data are compressed and others not compressed! In my Restful web services I have decompressed all data and tried to put them in one zip file so that I can get them for android. With your suggestion I saw that I have to convert the response to String (private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is)) but what I wanted is to take this stream and get my File back. Because I cannot convert all my bytes to string. Thank you